# Is it possible to copy data from from Amazon S3 objects in Requester Pays Buckets using Azure Data Factory V2?

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory exist connection to Amason S3 where I can set AccessKey and SecretKey. After I create Linked Service and try to use dataset in copy activity I get 403 error when I try to get data from requester pays bucket. In Amazon S3 documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html
writes that it just need to put additional header to access this data. Does exist any ways to put this header in Amazon dataset or other workarounds?

Comment: Do you have set the right permissions on S3? To copy data from Amazon S3, you have to make sure that you have been granted the following permissions s3:ListBucket or s3:GetBucketLocation for Amazon S3 Bucket Operations  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service#required-permissions

Comment: Yes, I have following permissions on this bucket. The only difference that this bucket is pay accept. For example with S3 browser (http://s3browser.com) I should accept pay request dialog, but I can't see such functionality in Data Factory V2